# Invalid object name when copying rows from one database to another

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to copy records from one database to another on the same server.  It keeps giving me an Invalid Object Name error for the database I am copying from, but the name is correct.  Target database is BS_Database and the Source Database is BS_Copy.  Here is my query:

```
    Insert into BS_Database.tbl_Training_Attempt_New
([AttemptId]
      ,[RequirementId]
      ,[EmployeeCompanyId]
      ,[TaskId]
      ,[CourseId]
      ,[RecordId]
      ,[StartDate]
      ,[Score]
      ,[IsComplete]
      ,[CompleteDate]
      ,[IsPassed]
      ,[Active]
      ,[TimeInSession])
      SELECT
      [AttemptId]
      ,[RequirementId]
      ,[EmployeeCompanyId]
      ,[TaskId]
      ,[CourseId]
      ,[RecordId]
      ,[StartDate]
      ,[Score]
      ,[IsComplete]
      ,[CompleteDate]
      ,[IsPassed]
      ,[Active]
      ,[TimeInSession]
      FROM BS_Copy.tbl_Training_Attempts_New WHERE
      IsPassed = 0
```

Comment: You missed schema part - you at least need `Insert into BS_Database..tbl_Training_Attempt_New ... FROM BS_Copy..tbl_Training_Attempts_New`, if all your tables reside in dbo schema.

Comment: That query only uses 2 part naming; it isn't cross database.

Comment: So I need more than just the name of the database, and the table?  I need to add the "dbo" in front of each table name?

Comment: BS_Copy.dbo.[tbl_Training_Attempts_New].  This does not work either.

Comment: You should **always** be defining the schema when referencing an objects, @RaniRadcliff . In the above `BS_Database.tbl_Training_Attempt_New` references the object `tbl_Training_Attempt_New` on the **schema** `BS_Database` in the database you are currently connected to. To reference an object in a different database, then the format needs to be `DatabaseName.SchemaName.ObjectName`.

Comment: you need that also for BS_Database.dbo.tbl_Training_Attempt_New. Every table (view, stored proc,..) needs db and schema and table name if you are quering cross database

Comment: Not necessary,. @GuidoG. *Presumably* the OP is connected to either the destination or source database; we just don't know which. They only need 3 part naming for the object that isn't in the database that they are connected to. In the above, only one of the objects should require 3 part naming (`DatabaseName.SchemaName.ObjectName`), while the should have require 2 part naming (`SchemaName.ObjectName`).

Comment: DatabaseName = BS_Copy, SchemName would be "dbo"?  and Table name tbl_Training_Attempt_new, right?

Comment: @Larnu Yes you are right, I myself do it for all objects in every database when quering cross database, but for the connected database it is indeed not needed. I stand corrected

Comment: *Assuming* you are using the default schema, then yes it would be `dbo`, @RaniRadcliff . If you aren't using the default schema, we have no idea what the schema name would be,

Comment: When I add the dbo, I get Reference to database and/or server name in 'BS_Database.dbo.tbl_Training_Attempt_New' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: Are you using Azure SQL database by chance? If yes, then https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/

Comment: @Arvo - yes it is an Azure database.  I am in SSMS.  I didn't think the the query would have to be written differently.  I will check out the blog.  Thanks!

Comment: This is starting to smell of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) now. Azure SQL Databases are contained databases by design, you can't do cross database queries and normally the "requirement" to means a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you follow this way every thing will gong to be transferred

```
insert into [Destination db].[schema].[table name](Column1,column2,...)
select * from [Source db].[schema].[table name](Column1,column2,.....) where column1=1 and ......
```

in your query you missed schema if you follow default schema should be specify **dbo**